# Using both CRUD and Secure module in Play Framework

Tags: java, model-view-controller, playframework

I'm wondering how to use CRUD with Secure module without securing the entire controller.

I have a BlogPost model with a controller named BlogPosts. Since I want the administrators to be able to use the CRUD back-office to create, update and delete posts, the controller extends CRUD and uses Secure :

```
@With(Secure.class)
public class BlogPosts extends CRUD {

}
```

But now I want to list the blog posts on the home page. I cannot use this controller since it is restricted to authenticated users. And I do not want to create another controller.

So what is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

You can write your own @Before method that calls the Security check for all methods except *list*. Something like:

```
   @Before(unless="list")
   public static void before() {
      // Do security check
   }
```

It won't be as handy as the annotation but it will work.

See the [documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/controllers#before)

**EDIT ON COMMENT TO CLARIFY**

I see the answer was slightly ambiguous. The idea is to remove the `@With()` annotation and create your own local `@Before` method that will be executed on all methods *except* `list`. That method can then delegate the processing to Secure.before (as it is a static method with no params)

Now that I think about it, you could just add the `unless` restriction to the method in `Secure` class, it should work for this scenario although it means mixing some concepts (so I would not do it in my project).

Comment: So you are simply bypassing the Secure module? How do you call the security check if you do not have the @With(Secure.class) annotation? And how do you handle authentication to the CRUD back-office?

Answer (score 2):

Just get the `BlogPost` items via JPA in your other controller:

```
public static void listBlogs() {
    render(BlogPost.findAll());
}
```

Comment: Then you're suggesting to create another controller, which I think would be a duplicate of BlogPosts. How would you name it? Another solution would be to put this in Application controller.

Comment: Hi, you don't need to create a specific controller to retrieve the list of the blog posts. It is already covered by the inheritance of the superclass Model in your entity BlogPost, as suggested by BlogPost.findAll().

Comment: Yes, use another controller.  The `BlogPosts` class should only be used for admin UIs.

Comment: So I'll have to duplicate all the controllers needed for administration? That sounded like dirty to me.
@WiseTechi I was talking about the controller you place the method listBlogs() in.